# "NotSerializableException" occurs when running Corda-Sample on Intellij

Tags: corda

1.Clone Sample like "git clone https://github.com/corda/samples"

2.Open Corda-Sample by Intellij

3.Chose"Run Example Cordapp - Kotlin" And Run

4.Open "build.gradle"(Clients/src) And Run "runPartyAServer" and "runPartyBServer"

5.Access "http://localhost:50005/" And "Create IOU"

6.Exception occured.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.flow.ExampleFlow$Initiator was not found by the node, check the Node containing the CorDapp that implements com.example.flow.ExampleFlow$Initiator is loaded and on the Classpath
```

How can I solve this Exception?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running nodes?

This command is example 「cordapp-example」,

```
./cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/build/nodes/runnodes
```

If the build folder does not exist, build it.

This command is build command, (Please run 「cordapp-example」directory)

```
./gradlew clean deployNodes
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you pzita.but you write how to run from the terminal, but that's not necessary for me.
What I need is a way to run and debug Corda Node and Spring Boot from Intellij.